# git - confusion with branch heads?

Tags: git, branch

I created a branch bbb_dev from a branch bbb. After having commited and pushed by doing

```
git push origin bbb_dev
```

I still get, when typing 'git status' the message

```
On branch bbb_dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/bbb' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So it looks that the branch bbb_dev is still somehow connected to the branch bbb. I'd like to push commits to bbb_dev by simply doing 'git push'... Is there any risk that changes done to bbb_dev will be done also to bbb? Do I maybe need to set differently the head of bbb_dev?

Comment: Just for safety : I invite to check if the remote `bbb_dev` branch was created at all, and if it is up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link your local branch to a remote `bbb_dev` branch :

```
# from branch bbb_dev
git branch -u bbb_dev
```

If remote branch `bbb_dev` does not exist : push it and set upstream in one go :

```
git push origin -u bbb_dev:bbb_dev
```